# Sending data from html t mysql Error

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

That is the code error

```
Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL
syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version 
for the right syntax to use near 'order,visibility,comment,add) VALUES 
('cake', 'wonderful ', '1','0', '0'' at line 2
```

[image: this is my code]

[image: Here is my database table structure]

Comment: Sounds like `order` is a reserved word.  Wrap table/column names in back-ticks to explicitly tell the database that they are table/column names and not keywords.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html

Comment: We hate images.

Comment: Please post code as text in future

Comment: thanks i've changed the names and it works